# How to handle dynamic schema in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

My data looks like this:
row 1 - `{"id": "1", "object": "user","metadata": {"name": "1234"}}`
rows 2 - `{"id": "1", "object": "user","metadata": {"name": "1234","email": "abc@abc.com"}}`

I created the table using row 1
`metadata   RECORD  NULLABLE
metadata.tenant STRING  NULLABLE
object  STRING  NULLABLE
id  STRING  NULLABLE`

But my insert will fail on row 2. what should my schema look like so that it can handle changes in metadata field?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Can you help with this?

Comment: Can you just include `email` as a field in `metadata` even though it isn't present for the first row? Or are you saying that there are potentially other fields inside `metadata` as well?

Comment: Adding email will not help. There can be other fields in metadata.

Comment: The best you could do is to have `metadata` be a string column and use the `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` functions in that case.

Comment: agree with Elliott - that's the way to go. But make sure your string is valid JSON otherwise you will not be able to use JSON_EXTRACT... functions. Saying this because in your previous example  - this was not a case!

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had done. Metadata can include arrays also. Do you think I will be able to select/filter within metadata array when it is stored as a string. I am generating string using json.dumps `if key in ('metadata'):
                                row[key] = json.dumps(value)` I have noticed that it adds \" to escape " but do you think json_extract can handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example shown in your question  - I would go with below schema

```sql
[
  {
    "name": "id",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "object",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "metadata",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

And below is an example of how I would process it

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'user' AS object, '{"name": "BI Architect", "email": "abc@abc.com"}' AS metadata UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'expert', '{"name": "Elliott Brossard"}'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  object, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(metadata, '$.name') AS name,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(metadata, '$.email') AS email 
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable` 
ORDER BY id
```

resulted in below output

```sql
id  object  name                email    
1   user    BI Architect        abc@abc.com  
2   expert  Elliott Brossard    null
```

Comment: What if there is new field in metadata? And what if the new field is an array?

Comment: it is just string, so still will work! no matter how many new fields will be added - to extract them you will just need to adjust JSON PATH in JSON_EXTRACT function. That simple!

Comment: just to be clear metadata will be a string field. name and email don't need to be separate fields?

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. I am generating string using python json.dumps(value) `if key in ('metadata'): row[key] = json.dumps(value)` I have noticed that it adds \" to escape " but do you think json_extract can handle that?

Comment: just try and if any issues in resolving it  - post new specific question. hope you are getting more comfortable with how SO works. Meantime  - if my answer helped and you accepted it  - please also consider voting it up  - It is important on SO. This increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your next questions :o) please consider!