# Store Object with Arbitrary Properties in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load data into a table in bigquery in which one of the fields needs to hold a JSON object with arbitrary property names. Since there are an almost limitless amount of property names I have to expect, predefining all of the property names in a schema is not an option.

The data I am trying to insert looks like this:

```
{
  property1: "randomString",
  property2: 128,
  property3: {
    randomNestedProperty1: "value1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Where property3 is always named property3 yet can contain an arbitrary amount of properties inside. How would you define the schema for this object or create a field to hold property3 and all of its properties?

Edit: I should also like to clarify that every value in the object that property3 references is just a string. I.e. there are no nested objects in property3.

Comment: Why don't you store as JSON string all these and use query with the JSON functions as it was a column? You can also materialize to a column table some of your queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle dynamic schema in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178304/how-to-handle-dynamic-schema-in-bigquery)